# Why is my span element in a react component printing on a new line and not inline?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a react component and I am trying to place the input boxes to the right of the calendar.

```
class PayrollComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      val: 0,
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const inputElement = document.createElement("input");
    inputElement.setAttribute("type", "time");
    inputElement.setAttribute("className", "test");
    inputElement.style.margin = "10px";

    const inputContainer = document.getElementById("inputContainer");
    const br = document.createElement("br");
    // const textNode = document.createTextNode(" ");

    inputContainer.appendChild(inputElement);
    inputContainer.appendChild(inputElement);
    // inputContainer.appendChild(textNode);

    if ((this.state.val % 2 === 0) | (this.state.val === 2)) {
      inputContainer.appendChild(br);
    }
    console.log("Component updates by this many times: " + this.state.val);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>
          <CalendarComponent className="test" daysSelected={(days) => this.setState({ val: days + 1 })} /> <div id="inputContainer"></div>
        </span>
        <span>
          <div id="inputContainer" className="test"></div>
        </span>
        <p> {this.state.val} </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PayrollComponent;
```

I put two span elements next to each other in react but they don't appear that way in the dom. I thought this would put the calendar and input boxes in line with one another? I have attached a screenshot showing.[image]

I tried wrapping my calendar component and input container in span tags thinking this would have them inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, any element's `display` CSS property determines how it will be laid out. `<span>` and `<div>` have appropriate defaults, but they could be changed. No telling from your sample if they are. But even assuming they are not, you have not said what `<CalendarComponent>` is. If it is a block-level element, it does not matter if it is inside a span, it gets its own block. Changing its `display` to something else (e.g. `inline-block`) might help. See:

```html
<section>
  <span>
    side
  </span>
  <span>
    by
  </span>
  <span>
    side
  </span>
</section>

<hr>

<section>
  <span>
    <div>NOT side</div>
  </span>
  <span>
    by
  </span>
  <span>
    side
  </span>

<hr>

<section>
  <span>
    <div style="display: inline-block">IS side</div>
  </span>
  <span>
    by
  </span>
  <span>
    side
  </span>
</section>
```